# Windows Phone - Set Zoomlevel in Map

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps

I have on my map two pushpins with their longitude and latitude. But now I want to set the view of the map so that both points are seen. The Geocoordinate is the midpoint from both longitude and both latitude. But how can I set the zoomlevel, so that both points are seen?

```
    mymap.SetView(new Geocoordinate(((longitude1+longitude2)/2),((latitude1+latitude2)/2)), ?); // ? is the zoomlevel is search
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map.SetView(LocationRectangle) method, like

```
mymap.SetView(new LocationRectangle(northwestGeocoordinate, southeastGeocoordinate));
```

Details: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj663035(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj663035%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I set the two coordinates, the map zooms out or it gives an error :/

Comment: @user3493797 What co-ordinates are you using? Are you specifying northwest one followed by southeast one? Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: This is the problem. My both Geocoordinates are variable, sometimes there are in southwest and northeast :/ Have u a answer for this problem?

Comment: @user3493797 You can write your own logic to determine the northwest and southeast point from the two variables.  
Say your points are p1 and p2. Then northwest is Math.Max(p1.Latitude, p2.Latitude), Math.MIn(p1.Longitude, p2.Longitude). Similarly determine southeast and then call SetView.